# Including a JAR file in class path, but import statements giving me errors.

Tags: java, jar, import, classpath

I downloaded the JAR for the LingPipe language tool. (http://alias-i.com/lingpipe) I added some import statements as per their tutorial file here (http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/src/PolarityBasic.java).

Now I go to compile with:

```
javac -cp <PATH_TO>/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar:. LingPipeTester.java
```

After doing this I get errors on the import statments, such as:

```
LingPipeTester.java:4: package com.aliasi.classify does not exist
import com.aliasi.classify.Classified;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add `-verbose:class` which will output all class loading. See if your class is being loaded (sounds like not).

Comment: the -verbose:class option gives me this: javac: invalid flag: -verbose:class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: javac -cp <PATH>/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar:. -verbose:class LingPipeTester.java

Comment: My bad, `-verbose:class` is a runtime switch (`java`). I see that you are trying to compile. In that case I'd check your path to the lingpipe jar.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to give the absolute path.

```
<PATH_TO>/C://lingpipe...
```

Comment: if it's on thesame path use     .(dot)/lingpipe.jar

Comment: using a file that's in thesame directory needs you to use a . (dot) in front of your filepath. or you have to give the absolute path

Comment: On a mac what would be the absolute path to say, downloads? Do you know? I thought I was giving it the absolute path.

Comment: Google is your answer my friend. Like this [example](https://squarepenguin.co.uk/find-path-to-a-folder-on-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by compiling with

```
javac -cp lingpipe-4.1.0.jar LingPipeTester.java
```

Before when I did this I was getting an error on runtime but it was because I wasn't including the current directory in the filepath when running it.